# Finding the restore progress of SQL server from inside c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, backup, progress, database-restore

I know this is most-likely a simple question but when you restore a database from inside SQL management studio you can set the update interval with stats

```
RESTORE DATABASE [test] FROM  DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Backup\test.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
```

If I wanted to execute that line of code from inside c# how would i get the progress? Currently I just use `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` but I can not figure out how to get the progress.

Also, if it is any faster, using the Microsoft.SQLServer namespace is acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExecuteNonQuery is only going to return once the operation is complete.  There might be a way to monitor its progress from a connection on another thread or to use an async call, but you could also look at using SMO, which provides a way to register callbacks see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.restore.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162133.aspx with [PercentComplete event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backuprestorebase.percentcomplete.aspx)

Comment: Do you know if the SQL2008 SDK is backwards compatible with the 2005 and 2000 servers OR is the SQL2000 SDK forward compatible. (I need to administer a 2000 and 2005 instance on the same server and some point in the future a 2008 instance)

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain I would use the latest SDK and test against the old servers.  That has the highest likelihood of success.  The 2000 SDK didn't even have SMO (it had something called SQL-DMO).

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain In SQL Server 2000, for Remus' solution, you will need to use the sysprocesses table, because that DMV was not available in that version.

Comment: In researching SMO's they work with compatibility level 80 (sql2000) and up.

Answer (score 5):

Before you start the operation get the connection session id:

```
SELECT @@SPID;
```

Then start your backup request. From a different connection, query [`sys.dm_exec_requests`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx) and look at percent_complete for the session that executes the restore statement:

> Percentage of work completed for the
>   following commands:
>
> - ALTER INDEX REORGANIZE
> - AUTO_SHRINK option with ALTER DATABASE
> - BACKUP DATABASE
> - CREATE INDEX
> - DBCC CHECKDB
> - DBCC CHECKFILEGROUP
> - DBCC CHECKTABLE
> - DBCC INDEXDEFRAG
> - DBCC SHRINKDATABASE
> - DBCC SHRINKFILE
> - KILL (Transact-SQL)
> - **RESTORE DATABASE**
> - UPDATE STATISTICS.